# How to get XCTAttachments in jenkins

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, fastlane

In the UItests screenshots are attached to the XCTest report like this:

```
let screenshot = windows.firstMatch.screenshot()
let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
attachment.name = named
sender.add(attachment)
```

and they shou up in the report like this:

[image: report]

What I want to do, is to show the screenshots as artifacts in the jenkins job. How can I retrieve those screenshots in jenkins?

or in other words, are those attachments located somewhere on disc, or could I save them somewhere automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to run the [archiveArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) step in your pipeline and pull in the attachments.   Once you do, they'll show on the job build view in Jenkins.   I have pipeline code similar to the following for that.

```
dir('./build/DerivedData/Logs/Test/Attachments') {
    //Archive the screenshots 
    archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/*.png'
    archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/*.jpg'
}
```